# Internal socket receive buffer implementation

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, buffer

I’m working on an embedded application, where i receive some sensor values over UDP. The board I’m using runs the 2.4 kernel on an ARM processor. The problem is the following: once my internal socket buffer is full only the newest value gets replaced. So the internal buffer is not implemented as a circular buffer, which it should be, as i found out studying some articles. Can i somehow change the behaviour of the internal receive buffer?

I already found out that there is no way to "flush" that buffer from the application side. The best idea I’ve got is checking whether the receive buffer is full, before receiving any packets and if so fist read out all the old packets manually. Is there any better approach?

I hope it's somehow clear what I mean, any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "internal receive buffer"? Internal to what? Are you trying to fix it, or work round its deficiencies?

Comment: When you call `recv_from` you're reading from a kernel implemented buffer, that is the one i mean. I don't need to fix it, it just needs to work properly. I've just tested my server application on my development computer (Ubuntu 14.10) and there the internal buffer behaves as expected, i.e. the old values are dropped.

Answer (score 0):

> The best idea I’ve got is checking whether the receive buffer is full,
>   before receiving any packets and if so fist read out all the old
>   packets manually.

I'd not bother checking whether the receive buffer is full, rather always read all packets until no more are there and use the last received, which contains the newest value.